# Laravel relationship not returning anything

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

My problem is that my relationship isn't working in my view. Do you guys see anything wrong?

Model retailer

```
public function retailerProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'name');
}
```

Model product

```
public function retailerProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Retailer::class, 'retailer_id');
}
```

View

```
@if(!empty($shopGSM->retailerProduct->name))
                {{ $shopGSM->retailerProduct->name  }}
@endif
```

Comment: Show us where and how do you get `$shopGSM`.

Comment: We need more information regarding your table structure and how are you passing those variables to the view.